# How does a colon (:) preceding a variable name within quotes work?

Tags: php, yii

I assume that `:parent_id` evaluates to a number. But, how exactly does this piece of code work? When should I use this syntax (`:name`)?

```
$data = Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=:parent_id',array(
                ':parent_id' => (int) $_POST['Current-Controller']['country_id']
        ));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colon doesn't have any special meaning. The pattern `:parent_id` as a whole does, but that's only because you chose to use it as a variable name in the `WHERE` condition (`parent_id=:parent_id`).

You could just as well have chosen to write

```
$data=Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=the_quick_brown_fox',
     array('the_quick_brown_fox'=>(int) $_POST['Current-Controller']['country_id']));
```

In practice the colon is used because there's the risk of the name you choose for the variable also being present as a legitimate part of the condition, in which case all instances of it will be replaced with the value and results will be unexpected.

For example, this:

```
$data=Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=parent_id',
     array('parent_id'=> 1 /*anything, really*/));
```

would result in the condition `1=1`, which would match all records.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is it just a string? If parent_id is 2, then does :parent_id evaluate to 2 within the quotes? It doesn't appear that way inside of the html. I saw another example where for example $length was passed into a function and then the author used :length within the function.

Comment: @user1417526: No, the replacement is performed afterwards (while the database query is being processed).

Comment: @Jon, any proof links that you can omit the colons?